# Papers about Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP)

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'm searching for relative (after 2000) new papers about TSP.
All the papers I have found were quite hard and needed high level
mathematical skills. I'm looking for papers that are simple to read
for someone who has simple college mathematic knowledge and good
programming knowledge in Java and C (I didn't find any current paper
implementing TSP with these languages).

Any hints will be highly appreciated.

---

(edit)

What Im trying to say is that im searching for papers that dont need to understand
difficult formulas. For instance some papers describe algorithms, or the philosophy 
of solution. It isnt necessary to implement that algorithm, just describe the techniques.
Maybe using some simple geometry ...

I found some papers based on Lin-Kernighan methods, which seemed ok ...

Comment: Sorry to say, TSP is not a simple college level problem. All good information on it will require heavy understanding on computational theory, complexity analysis etc. I guess it's better to ask the question on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The problem is hard, so as mentioned, heavy math is involved.  You can try to muddle through http://code.google.com/p/java-traveling-salesman/.  You are looking for something similar to a paper to understand relativity with only knowledge of algebra.

Answer (score 6):

I'm somewhat familiar with the TSP literature, and I doubt there's anything matching your criteria; the simpler, less mathematical algorithms were pioneered long before your cutoff.

David S. Johnson and coauthors have some articles that I like: http://www2.research.att.com/~dsj/papers.html , in particular #1 and #3 under Traveling Salesman Problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple, here is one page that describes using space filling curves to find a good solution (not optimal obviously).  Of course, a webpage is not a paper.  Nor do I know if the ideas presented there were created after 2000.  If this is more of what you are looking for, perhaps you should edit your question, or provide an example.

http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~jjb/mow/mow.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

1) Study chapter 11-Guided Local Search and Chapter 12- Iterated Local Search from Handbook of Metaheuristics(2010), each of these has a section describing how GLS and ILS are designed for TSP. Both ILS and GLS are interesting and quite easy to implement.

2) Check this paper: "Guided local search and its application to the traveling salesman problem"

3) Find the Ruby code for these algorithms [here](http://www.cleveralgorithms.com/nature-inspired/index.html) , and rewrite it in Java